# When will Custom Resource Providers get out of public preview

Tags: azure, azure-custom-providers

Since 2019 Custom Resource Providers are still in public preview, this prevents partners and organizations to put bigger investments in creating additional services on the platform as the service capability might be removed, changed or never be supported.

Is there any outlook by when the service might be released/published? If not at least some sort of roadmap, what is missing to get it there?

I've checked the documentation and GitHub Issues, but there is not much movement on the CustomServiceProvider portion of Azure.